# Sum a list of options in Scala using tail recursion and match expressions

Tags: scala

i have to make a tail recursive program using match expressions which will print the sum of List of type `List[Option[Double]]`
f.e `List(Some(1), ..., Some(n)) --> Some(1 + ... + n)`
But it only sum the list which have a positive number so when Some(d) and d < 0 it doesnt count.

```
List(Some(1.0),Some(2.0), Some(-3.0) ---> Some(3.0)
```

When there are not any elements which are positive it should return `None`

```
sumuj(List(Some(2.0), Some(4.0), Some(-3.0), None, Some(-3.0), None, Some(1.0))) returns Some(7.0)
```

I only know how to sum list only of Some(value), do not know how to sum only positive arguments.

```
def sumuj(l: List[Option[Double]]): Option[Double] = {
  def helper(l: List[Option[Double]], acc: Double): Option[Double] = {
    l match {
      case head :: tail => head match {
        case Some(value)  => helper(tail, acc + value)
      }
      case Nil => Some(acc)
    }
  }
  helper(l, acc = 1)
}
println(sumuj(List(Some(2.0), Some(4.0), Some(-3.0))))
```

Comment: Your function is not handling the `None` once you do that it should be pretty straightforward to include the handling of negative numbers, you just need to drop an `if` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [pattern match guard](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html#pattern-guards) for that:

```
def sumPositives(l: List[Option[Double]]) = {
  @tailrec
  def sumPositives0(l: List[Option[Double]], acc: Double): Option[Double] =
    l match {
      case Some(head) :: tail if head > 0 => sumPositives0(tail, acc + head)
      case _ :: tail                      => sumPositives0(tail, acc)
      case Nil                            => Some(acc)
    }
  sumPositives0(l, acc = 1)
}
```

And then:

```
println(sumPositives(List(Some(2.0), Some(4.0), Some(-3.0))))
```

Yields:

```
Some(7.0)
```

Comment: I got the impression that in the presence of a single `None` or a single negative number the function should return `None` _(kind of like a `traverse`)_ - But it may be just may bad English, and in any case it should be straightforward for OP  to change the code if needed.

Comment: It should return None if there are not any Some(values) which are positive. f.e (List(Some(-2.0), Some(-4.0), Some(-3.0) )

Comment: Thanks for help! Thats what i needed :)